# Creating a stack of triangles that increase in size in python

Tags: python

Trying to  get to grips with python,
I have an activity to do which in is to create 4 triangles one on top of the other while increasing in size to look like the below image.

```
from turtle import *
trisize = 80
for triangles in range(1, 5):
    forward(trisize)
    left(120)
    forward(trisize)
    left(120)
    forward(trisize)
    left(120)
    penup()
    forward(trisize)
    left(120)
    forward(trisize)
    left(60)
    forward(20)
    left(180)
    pendown()
    trisize = trisize + 20
```

Where am I going wrong? I'm also suppose to add a second loop to this somewhere?.

Thanks

Comment: First: please include the image and your code online in your question so that everyone can see it, second try to make functions to better encapsulate your code

Answer (score 0):

The reason the triangles aren't aligning as you would expect is that you aren't moving far enough to the left with the line `forward(20)` at line 15. In order for the triangle to line up with the triangle prior to it you would need to move left by half the base width of the new triangle (which in your case is trisize/2+10 (half the base width of the old triangle, and half the increment).

To fix the problem with the alignment, increment trisize first and then change the line to `forward(trisize/2)` and avoid having a magic number.

Comment: Of course, William's answer about using a nested loop for the triangle rather than saying forward(trisize) left(120) forward(trisize) left(120) forward(trisize) left(120) would certainly make the code cleaner (it also will help make it much more intuitive as to what the code is actually doing. Seeing a for loop which draws a line and rotates three times is much more clear about drawing a triangle than 9 lines of instructions about draw a line rotating 120 degrees draw another line and so on).

Answer (score 0):

You have to end up at the top of the triangle after drawing it.  You can do that by drawing 5 sides (that last two being overdrawn) then reorient your turtle to point to the right again and go back half of a triangle's size to start the new triangle from its bottom left corner.

```
from turtle import *

size = 80
for _ in range(5):
    forward(-size//2)   # move to bottom left
    for _ in range(5):  # draw triangle, end up on top
        forward(size)
        left(120)
    left(120)           # complete rotation
    size += 20          # increase size
```